# how to handle error when third language is not define in node--custome.tpl.php

Tags: drupal-7, nodes

i am using field collection to define used language of translation of pages here is my code :

```
$value_node = ($content['field_translation']['#items'][0]['value']);
$value_node1 = ($content['field_translation']['#items'][1]['value']);

$value_node2 = ($content['field_translation']['#items'][2]['value']);
```

when page has 3 languages they work perfectly but when some page has 2 language they error on $value_node2.
and error is "Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in include() "

Answer (score 0):

The message you are describing is actually just a notice, and its because you are allowing notices to be displayed. This is great for development but bad for production. (see: /admin/config/development/logging for notice, error & warning display preferences)

To avoid seeing this notice simply put a check before you access that variable to make sure it's set.

```
if (isset($content['field_translation']['#items'][2]['value'])) {
  $value_node2 = ($content['field_translation']['#items'][2]['value']);
}
```